Unity bug with web build
We have made build for web (Webgl) via Unity standard approach. The application is running and start-up well.
Application has to connect to Nakama game server, we are using Nakama Unity package for this action.
By clicking on Connect button Nakama client code is invoking and we get an error with text:

Unable to open DLL! Dynamic linking is not supported in WebAssembly builds due to limitations to performance and code size. Please statically link in the needed libraries.

The standard build for Mac is working well, without errors. This happens only with web build.
Do we need to make any special config for Unity web build to solve this problem? How can we statically link Nakama client library?
We tried different settings, but it didn’t help

I never used Nakama, but did you setup your sockets correctly? In WebGL builds you can not use any normal socket connections. You can only use WebSockets. In the documentation it mentioned what you need to do. Have you done that?
